# A good way to expire specific documents in one collection and add them to another collection on expiry

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using Nodejs and MongoDB driver.

**A two part question**

1. I have a collection which is called `openOffers` which I want to expire when it hits the time `closeOfferAt`. I know that MongoDB offers a TTL, `expireAt` and `expireAfterSeconds`. But, when I use these, the same TTL is applied to all the documents in a particular collection. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. I want document level custom expiry. Any syntax might be very useful!
   Docs in `openOffers`

```
{
 "_id":"12345",
 "data": {...},
 "closeOfferAt" : "2022-02-21T23:22:34.023Z"
}
```

2. I want to push these expired documents to another collection `openOfferLog`. This is so that I can retain the document for later analysis.

**Current approach**:
I haven't figured a way to have a customized TTL on each doc in `openOffers`. But, I currently insert docs into both, `openOffers` and `openOffersLog` together, and any data change in `openOffers` has to be separately propagated to `openOffersLog` to ensure consistency. There has to be a better scalable approach I suppose.

**EDIT-1:**

I'm looking for some syntax logic that I can use for the above use case. If not possible with the current MongoDB driver, I'm looking for an alternative solution with NodeJS code I can experiment with. I'm new to both NodeJS and MongoDB -- so any reasoning supporting the solution would be super useful as well.

Comment: check [Scheduled Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/triggers/scheduled-triggers/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to implement TTL indexes.

- Delete after a certain amount of time - *this is you have already implemented*
- Delete at a specific clock time - *for the detailed answers you can visit the [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/#expire-documents-at-a-specific-clock-time)*

So the second option fulfills your expectation,

1. Just set `0` (zero) in `expireAfterSeconds` field while creating an index,

   ```
   db.collection.createIndex({ "closeOfferAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 })
   ```
2. just set the expiration date in `closeOfferAt` while inserting the document, this will remove the document at a particular timestamp.

   ```
   db.collection.insert({
       "_id":"12345",
       "data": {...},
       "closeOfferAt" : ISODate("2022-02-23T06:14:15.840Z")
   })
   ```

Comment: What effect does ```expireAfterSeconds: 0``` have? Also, are there better alternatives to achieving the same output? Like is this a good soln for production environment?

Comment: I'm also trying to get guidance on part (2) of the question where it might be logging in an amateur way

Comment: I think it is better to insert documents in both the collections and as per the answer you can create ttl index, it will delete the document as per the specified date. I think yes this is  a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do not make your application logic depend on TTL indexes.

In your app you should have some scheduler that runs periodic tasks, some of them would move the finished offers to other collection and delete from the original even in bulk and no need to set a TTL index.

To keep consistency nothing better than a single source of truth, so if you can, avoid deleting and only change some status flag and timestamps.

A good use of a TTL index is to automatically clear old data after a relative long time, like one month or more. This keeps collection/indexes size in check.

Comment: I do understand the logic behind your answer. It seems like a good option for the long-term and would pursue it later on. Currently, I'm trying to develop a solution which serves a temporary purpose.

Comment: Finally, the below answer by @turivishal does work in terms of the purpose of the question. But, I'll be removing TTL as single source of truth makes more sense.